# Need to know if SharePoint Online can be used to create a .com site with searchable database

Tags: database, sharepoint, web, searchable

I need to create a website providing a searchable database for visitors to find providers of services in their area. I am sorry I do not know all the specific terms.

I was wondering if I can create such a site using SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 2):

yes you can create a com site and as well configure the search for more details on pricing and others please contact  microsoft
http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint-Online/Pages/default.aspx